# "Everyday an English word" or "Daily English word" or "An English word every day"

Tags: word-choice, titles

I need to write an English word to the blackboard each day. Which title is correct? I need something that shows purpose instead of something like "word of the day". And should I use "everyday" or "every day"?

Comment: You could always use ["A Word A Day"](http://wordsmith.org/words/today.html).

Comment: [Word of the Day Quiz](http://blog.dictionary.com/word-of-the-day-quiz-03032015/)

Comment: Does the blackboard write back?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Possibly; but a whiteboard writes black.

Comment: @Erik Kowal If OP counts them and never repeats, he will soon render the 'literally a floor or two full of the world's leading scientists on this issue, working at Google, as a part of their overall astounding (one grudgingly admits) efforts ' that Joe Blow writes about redundant.

Comment: Or not. People on ELU seem to invent a word a day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Everyday* as one word is an adjective meaning "ordinary" — something you might encounter every day. So one might have "an everyday English word" **but** that isn't what you want: an everyday English word is one like *and* or *that* or even *everyday.*

"An English word every day" would be a good title for a book which sets out a vocabulary like a diary, offering one word per day. The title of such a book could even be "A daily English word" or "Daily English words" — *daily* is often an adverb, but can be an adjective used in this way. It wouldn't normally be used as a heading for just one thing even if that changes each day.

There's nothing wrong with "Word of the Day": that is what your word is. It's quite a common title for a word which changes daily. Or anything else: restaurants might have a "Soup of the Day".

If you don't like "Word of the Day" you could simply use "Today's word".

Answer (score 1):

I don't see much wrong with

> English word of the day

There is a subtle difference in meaning from

> Daily English word

I think **Daily** has an implication of being routine. We speak of "our daily bread". While your intention is to deliver a word daily, I think you actually intend more than this: you chose a word mindfully because you see it as important. If I were doing such a teaching exercise I would certainly try to do that, perhaps choosing a word on the basis of current affairs or other lessons in the week.

By saying

> English word of the day

You are implying the selection of a specific word for today. The focus is on **today** rather than on the repeating series implied by **daily**.